# What's the difference between RouteCollection and Route Table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-2

Can you tell the difference between RouteCollection and Route Table?

I tried a lot to search at Google. But could not found any references.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `RouteTable` is a class that stores the URL routes for your application.

A `RouteCollection` provides a collection of route information to be used when mapping a URI to a controller action.

The `RouteTable` contains a property called `Routes` that will return a `RouteCollection`. The `RouteTable` uses a `RouteCollection` in order to store all the URL routing information it needs to accurately direct URI's to the correct controller action.

In your global.asax you will register the routes that will map to various controller actions by specifying the following:

```
/// <summary>
/// Executed when the application starts.
/// </summary>
protected void Application_Start()
{
   RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

Then a route will be added to the `RouteCollection` in the following way:

```
/// <summary>
/// Registers the routes used by the application.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="routes">Routes to register.</param>
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
   routes.MapRoute(
     "Error", 
     "Error", 
     new { controller = "Error", action = "Error" });
}
```

This shows how the actual route information is stored in a `RouteCollection`, which in turn is referenced via the `RouteTable`.

Comment: how can i import RouteTable in .net standard 2 project